# Python function definition with function as optional argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to have a function as an optional argument
of another function in python but it is not clear for me how I can do that.

For example I define the following function:

```
import os, time, datetime

def f(t=datetime.datetime.now()):
    return t.timetuple()
```

I have placed `t=datetime.datetime.now()`
in order for the argument to be optional so 
to be able to call `f()` with no arguments.

Now whenever in time I execute `f()` I get the same datetime A (which is wrong according to what I expect), but whenever in time I execute `f(datetime.datetime.now())` I get different datetimes (which is correct as expected).

For example

```
>>> f()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=15, tm_min=36, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=171, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> f()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=15, tm_min=36, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=171, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> f(datetime.datetime.now())
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=15, tm_min=37, tm_sec=1, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=171, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> f()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=15, tm_min=36, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=171, tm_isdst=-1)
```

So why the fourth call returns me back to min 36 and sec 2
while the call was made before that?
Why the first two calls give the same exact time even if I let plenty of time between them?

Comment: Get rid of the extra parentheses in the function definition... you're *calling the method* at definition time.

Comment: which one is redundant ?

Comment: Really? There's only one pair you can remove without a syntax error...

Comment: removing the first and calling f() gives me an Attribute error, removing the second and calling f() returns just the object. In any case by removing the parentheses I do not get the desired result which is an output when calling f(), not to mention getting the correct output. I do not thing the problem is in the parentheses.

Comment: You need to move the *calling* parentheses from the definition line into the function body.

Comment: It is not clear what should I do, provide an example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by flask, the default value is evaluated when the function is parsed, so it will be set to one time.

The typical solution to this, is to not have the default a mutable value. You can do the followings:

```
def f(t=None):
    if not t:
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
    return t.timetuple()
```

BTW, for the readers' benefit, you should try to use meaningful method and variable names.

Comment: ... it is dlask no flask. I can't edit that ( 6 char min for edit)

Comment: @pebox11 You've accepted this as an answer, but this doesn't answer your question - this is not passing a function as a parameter.

Comment: I think an optional argument is a parameter. I am sorry if I confused you.

Comment: You should generally test `None` by *identity*; `if t is None:`

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the function from being evaluated by assigning the function when loading it into your second function.

```
import datetime

def f(t = datetime.datetime.now()):
    return t.timetuple()

def main(ff=f):
    print ff
    print ff()

>>> main()
<function f at 0x10a4e6938>
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=15, tm_min=39, tm_sec=28, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=171, tm_isdst=-1)
```

**edit:** function is always evaluated in parameter. Solution: decouple it's assignment from the parameter

```
def f(t="now"):
    if t=="now":
        return datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()
    else:
        return t.timetuple()

def main(ff=f):
    print ff
    print ff()

import time
main()
time.sleep(3)
main()
```

Comment: It does not work. Sequential execution of main() within, say 3 seconds, gives me the same time, where it shouldn't

Comment: You are correct, I made an edit which has a solution although it's kind of hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the optional parameter is the *function* for datetime now - no parentheses, as @jonsharpe was recommending. Calling f calls the default function, and calling it twice returns two different times:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def f(t=datetime.datetime.now):
...     return t()
... 
>>> f()
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 6, 10, 698000)

>>> f()
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 6, 12, 269000)
```

Or you can pass in another function, here a test one, and override `t`. Calling f() calls the function passed in:

```
>>> def test():
...     return "hi"
... 
>>> f(t=test)
'hi'
```

Comment: Say you have stored in variable `t` the value `datetime.datetime.now()`. Then `f(t)` is a `TypeError` cause datetime.datetime is not callable. So what you provided is not completely correct.

Comment: I think my problem is that your title says "*function as optional argument*" and your question says "*I would like to have a function as an optional argument*" but you don't actually want that, you want "*optional argument evaluated at runtime instead of compile time*". Passing a function around as a parameter to another function is a useful thing in itself.

Comment: I apologize if I was not precise enough

Answer (score -1):

The default parameter value is evaluated only once when the function is defined.

Comment: maybe, but how can I avoid that?